# How long can I expect to wait for the approval of a K-1 (fiancée) visa?

Tags: usa, spain, k1-visa

My fiancée is an American citizen and I'm from Spain. We got engaged in Spain, but we wanted to marry in the US (and we would like to stay there after). I saw the K-1 visa and it is exactly our situation, so it seemed like a great idea.

The problem I see now is that the time we have to wait to get the approval according to the .gov official websites is insane. So I wanted to know if we have to really wait 2 years to get a response.

The time it says we have to wait is:

- 13 months (in Texas, I don't know if we can choose Nebraska for a shorter time) for the processing of a I-129F petition.

  - source: https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/
- 197 days for the Visa appointment.

  - source: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html
- More time for the embassy to do administrative work.

At this point I don't know if there is a better option rather than the K-1 Visa, or if these times are really inflated and it will be less time, because they look crazy to me.

Comment: I can't confirm the times but as the American half of a international marriage 34 years ago I can confirm they were insanely slow even then and my understanding is they have gotten worse as time goes on.

Comment: In Canada the processing times for fiance visas are truly this slow.  Also, in the US, the processing times for student visas are also this slow.  So I would guess that these times are more or less accurate.